# How do I properly combine these SELECTS (MySQL)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get all my posts data to show it on my webpage with this SELECT. I have my table posts that contains most of the posts (+ replies) data and a table social that tracks who views and likes it(each like is a new row).
Normally I can get the username, post time, content... but I'm struggling to get the number of views the post gets, the number of likes, and the number of replies in the same SELECT. My base SELECT looks like this:

```
SELECT posts.username, posts.time, cat.cat_name, 
posts.title, posts.content, posts.reply, 
posts.user_file, posts.audio, social.id, 
social.views, social.likes 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN user on posts.user_id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN cat ON posts.cat_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN social ON posts.id = social.post_id
```

If I wanted to get the number of comments per post I would use
(if the value inside reply is 0 it's a post if it's a reply it contains the post id it's referring to):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `comments` FROM posts GROUP BY reply
/* this returns an error: SQL Error (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row */
```

And I would get the number of likes and views like this:

```
SELECT MAX(social.views) AS views FROM social GROUP BY post_id

SELECT social.likes FROM social WHERE social.id = (SELECT MAX(social.id) FROM social GROUP BY post_id
```

But if I use it together in the earlier SELECT it just fills every row with the same number. Example:

```
... posts.audio, social.id, (SELECT MAX(social.views) AS views FROM social GROUP BY post_id) FROM posts ...
```

This just fills every row even if it shouldn't have views with 25 (correct value for 1 specific row but wrong for everything else).

What would be a proper way of making a bigger SELECT like this?

Not sure if it matters but I am using it with a MySQL module in NodeJS.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  It is not obvious what is in your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
SELECT posts.username, posts.time, cat.cat_name, 
posts.title, posts.content, posts.reply, 
posts.user_file, posts.audio, 
COUNT(social.views), COUNT(social.likes)
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN user on posts.user_id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN cat ON posts.cat_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN social ON posts.id = social.post_id
GROUP BY
posts.username, posts.time, cat.cat_name, 
posts.title, posts.content, posts.reply, 
posts.user_file, posts.audio
```

Comment: Thanks. Your post was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest I've gotten to SELECTing everything in one query but I still don't have a way of counting the number of comments:

```
SELECT posts.username, posts.time, cat.cat_name, 
posts.title, posts.content, posts.reply,
posts.user_file, posts.audio,
social.views, social.likes
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN user on posts.user_id = user.id 
LEFT JOIN cat ON posts.cat_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN social ON posts.id = social.post_id
WHERE social.likes IN (SELECT social.likes FROM social 
WHERE social.id IN (SELECT MAX(social.id) 
FROM social GROUP BY post_id))
GROUP BY social.post_id
HAVING posts.reply = 0
```